# Save vectors to file in Python with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a variable with a numeric value, a variable with a string value, and two vectors defined with NumPy

```
a = 10
b = "text string"
positions = np.array([])
forces = np.array([])
```

I want to save these values to a file. I've used http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html to save the two vectors with

```
np.savetxt('test.out', (positions,forces))
```

but I also need to store the values of `a` and `b`.

How is this possible?

Comment: You could add `a` and `b` to the header with the `header` keyword argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would recommend using `numpy.savez` and `numpy.load`. For example:

```
numpy.savez('test.npz', a=a, b=b, positions=positions, forces=forces)
```

You can load it again like this:

```
data = numpy.load('test.npz')
a = data['a']
```